# Line by line comparison of text files - length error

Tags: python-3.x, text, string-comparison

```
#create empty list for wbm.txt
wbm_lines = []

#read the file and append each line to the empty list
with open('wbm.txt') as file_to_read:
    for line in file_to_read:
        wbm_lines.append(line)

i = 1

#create empty list for docu.txt
docu_lines = []
#read the file and append each line to the empty list
with open('docu.txt') as file_to_read:
    for line in file_to_read:
        docu_lines.append(line)
        
if len(wbm_lines) > len(docu_lines):
    for line in wbm_lines:
        if line != docu_lines:
            print("Line " + str(i) + " do not match")
            print('wbm.txt ' + wbm_lines[i])
            print('docu.txt ' + docu_lines[i])
            i += 1

else:
    for line in docu_lines:
        if line != wbm_lines:
            try:
                print("Line " + str(i) + " do not match")
                print('wbm.txt ' + wbm_lines[i])
                print('docu.txt ' + docu_lines[i])
                i += 1
            except:
                continue
```

But I am getting an error:

```
print('docu.txt ' + docu_lines[i])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The problem is that the two text files have different lengths. How can I resolve this?
Ideally, I would like to print something like `---` in place of the non-existent line, while printing the other line normally.